# One array affecting the other, both arrays declared separately

Tags: c, arrays

I was programming some code and I ran into this problem. I declared two arrays, one array is called start which is initalized to the string hello. The second array is called user and is supposed to be declared as **_** with the for loop. What happens though is that my array called start is modified so my output looks like this:

```
Printed word: Hello

Array Length: 5

_____o
```

Why is my start array being rewritten? Sorry if this is a noob question I'm learning by myself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{   
    size_t length = 0;
    char start [] = {"Hello"};
    printf("\nPrinted word: %s\n", start);
    length = strlen(start);
    printf("Array Length: %zi\n", length);

    char user[] = {0};

    for(size_t x = 0; x < length; x++){   //starting here
        user[x] = '_'; 
    }

    printf("%s\n",start);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` char array is defined with size = 1 with this definition

```
char user[] = {0};
```

The above definition means that the char array contains  one elment which is 0. The declaration of the `user` array in this way means that the size of the `user` array is deduced from the number of elements you put in the declaration.

In the for loop you are assigning values to the char array elements with indices do not exist for the `user` array . So you will get **undefined behaviour**

Change the declaration of your array to:

```
char user[length+1] = {0};
```

**EDIT**

If your compiler does not support the declaration of static array with variable length, you can use in this case dynamic memory allocation.

```
char *user = malloc((length+1) * sizeof(char));
```

And when the memory related to the `user` array pointer become useless in your program, do not forget to free it with

```
free(user);
```

Comment: The reason why I didn't put the variable length into the array declaration is because my compiler(xcode) gets an error that says "Variable-sized object may not be initialized". 
After putting an index of 10 the code worked fine though! So the missing index was the issue thank you. 
Is there a way to allow the array size to vary depending on the length though?

Comment: @user2335238 answer updated see Edit section for the response of your question

Answer (score 3):

You're not allocating any room in the `user` array, it has length 1 since you only provide a single initializer value. So when you write into it, you are doing so out of bounds and overflowing into memory used by other variables.

Also, for quoted strings the braces are not needed, it should be:

```
const char start[] = "Hello";
```

or

```
const char *start = "Hello";
```

lastly, even if there was room your loop is not properly terminating `user`, so the subsequent `printf()` with `%s` that expects a 0-terminated string will invoke undefined behavior.